# DateTimePicker in ToolStripControlHost cut off with different DPI settings

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, toolstripcontrolhost

[image: cut off date]

In the picture above there are two DateTimePicker controls in a Form. The upper DateTimePicker is inside a ToolStripControlHost, which is inside a ToolStrip control.

When I have my Windows DPI settings set to the defaults, the two DateTimePickers display correctly. However, after changing the DPI settings to Medium, the text of the upper DateTimePicker gets cut off and the control doesn't scale like the bottom DateTimePicker does.

Any ideas on how to get the DateTimePicker inside the ToolStripControlHost to display correctly?